# Split String in Powershell at every occurence of an @ and save substrings

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a string that might change depending to input in a gui. The string looks like this "@Donald @Trump @is @orange @and ...) So I have n Substrings that i want to split up and save like this: $word1 = "Donald" $word2 = "Trump".... $wordn = "xy" and I also need the value of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell `-split` operator will do what you want, except that instead of each substring being in a separate variable, they'll be in an array. Using your example,

```
$words = "@Donald @Trump @is @orange" -split "@"
```

will give you an array, where `$words.length` will be 5, and the words will be in `$words[1]` through `$words[4]` (with `$words[0]` being the empty string).

[SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) has good information on `-split`; so does [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6).

Comment: The querent added an "answer" which should have been a comment, inquiring whether `$words[1]` would be "`Donald`" (no space) or "`Donald `" (with space). The space would be included; to delete the space, one would want to call the [`trim()` method](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html), which is also well-documented at SS64.